# Align a header in all devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align a header [see the picture of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNazl.png). This works on chrome browser properly but its is not working on all the devices such as i-phone, i-pad or other devices. It merges when I change the view into another devices

The structure of my header is like 
| one big image(on left side)| icon - some text | icon1  icon2|.

I have tried few approaches to do it. But were unsuccessful. Below is the HTML code and CSS code. Please let me know if you need further clarifications. First time user of stack overflow.

P.S: The image have exact result what I want in all devices and browsers

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="header">


    <img  class="online-logo img-fluid" src="assets/images/online-logo.svg">
  <div class="header-cont">
    <div class="cap-cont">
        <img src="assets/images/some-icon.svg">
    <p style="cursor: pointer;">Some Text</p>

    </div>
</div>

  <div class="icon-cont">
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
#header
{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.online-logo {
  width: 18%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%; 
}
.header-cont .cap-cont {
  width: 103%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top: 3%;

}

.icon-cont {
  background: rgb(235,244,250);
  height: 55px;
  width: 32%;
 float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.header-cont .cap-cont p {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 23px;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-align: left;
   padding-top: 10px;

}

 .header-cont .cap-cont img{
   width: 5%;
  /* float: left;*/
   margin-top: 2%;
   margin-right: 1%;
   margin-left: 1%;
 }
 .header-cont .cap-cont {
  background: rgb(97,131,156);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail? I am not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: its not working in all devices

Comment: What part of it isn't working? What do you want it to do that it currently isn't doing?

Comment: Also, you appear to have drastically deviated from the default layout. I'd recommend checking Bootstrap's [**navbar guide**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) for a basis, and then working from there.

Comment: Aligning what to what?  If it works for some then give details on what devices it works and which it doesn't.  You have given one screenshot, is that the one which is correct or which isn't.  You might want to give one of each labelling them appropriately.

Comment: please check it now